# NoSuchMethodError with Play scala.tools.nsc.Settings.bootclasspath()

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, apple-m1, nosuchmethoderror

Unable to run Play server, getting NoSuchMethodError

Error message:

```
[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Enter to stop and go back to the console...)

[error] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.tools.nsc.settings.AbsSettings$AbsSetting scala.tools.nsc.Settings.bootclasspath()'
[error]         at play.twirl.compiler.TwirlCompiler$TemplateAsFunctionCompiler$CompilerInstance.compiler$lzycompute(TwirlCompiler.scala:503)
[error]         at play.twirl.compiler.TwirlCompiler$TemplateAsFunctionCompiler$CompilerInstance.compiler(TwirlCompiler.scala:481)
[error]         at play.twirl.compiler.TwirlCompiler$TemplateAsFunctionCompiler$PresentationCompiler$.<init>(TwirlCompiler.scala:549)
[error]         at play.twirl.compiler.TwirlCompiler$TemplateAsFunctionCompiler$PresentationCompiler$.<clinit>(TwirlCompiler.scala)
```

Configuration

1. Apple M1 Monterey
2. Scala 2.12.13
3. sbt 1.6.1
4. Play 2.7.9
5. Java OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.18.10.1

Already tried:

1. [apple-silicon-m1-playframework-broken-on-apple-silicon](https://discuss.lightbend.com/t/apple-silicon-m1-playframework-broken-on-apple-silicon/7924/17)

```html
addSbtPlugin("se.marcuslonnberg" % "sbt-docker" % "1.8.2")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.8.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-buildinfo" % "0.10.0") // For passing build information.
addSbtPlugin("io.github.davidmweber" % "flyway-sbt" % "7.4.0")

addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.6.1")


addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.7.9")

addSbtPlugin("com.github.cb372" % "sbt-explicit-dependencies" % "0.2.13")

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "1.1.0")

addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.10.0-RC1")

addSbtPlugin("ch.epfl.scala" % "sbt-scalafix" % "0.10.1")
```

```html
lazy val insight = (project in file("insight"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala, TypeSafeDockerPlugin, BuildInfoPlugin, BashStartScriptPlugin)
  .settings(commonSettings)
  .settings(baseBuildInfoKeys)
  .settings(
Global / cancelable := false,
version := insightVersion,
resolvers += "shibboleth-release" at "https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/repositories/releases", //for openSAML lib
libraryDependencies ++= insightDependencies,
libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value,
// automatically import template helpers for templates
TwirlKeys.templateImports ++= Seq(
  "********.utils.Environment",
  "********.models._",
  "controllers._",
  "templateHelpers._",
  "org.joda.time.DateTime"
),

// disable js asset stuff, we manage it on our own
Assets / JsEngineKeys.npmNodeModules := Nil,
TestAssets / JsEngineKeys.npmNodeModules := Nil,
// don't produce docs
Compile / doc / sources := Seq.empty,
Compile / packageDoc / publishArtifact := false,
PlayKeys.playMonitoredFiles := {
  val isUsingWebpackDevServer = Option(System.getenv("WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_PORT")).isDefined
  val filesList = PlayKeys.playMonitoredFiles.value
  if (isUsingWebpackDevServer) {
    (filesList --- baseDirectory.value / "public").get
  } else {
    filesList
  }
},
// run webpack when doing dist as well for staging and production
webpackDistTask := {
  val exitCode =
    Process("node" :: "node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js" :: "--progress" :: "--colors" :: Nil, baseDirectory.value) !

  if (exitCode != 0) {
    // webpack build has an error
    throw new RuntimeException(s"Webpack build error (exit code $exitCode). Check for errors above")
  }

  val versionRegex = "\\.([0-9a-f]*)\\.bundle".r
  val version =
    versionRegex.findFirstMatchIn(IO.readLines(baseDirectory.value / "conf" / "webpack-assets.json")(0)).get.group(1)
  IO.write(baseDirectory.value / "conf" / "version.conf", s"webpack.version=$version".getBytes)
},
dist := (dist dependsOn webpackDistTask).value
  )
  .settings(commonDockerSettings)
  .settings(dockerBuildInsight)
  .dependsOn(knowledge)
```

Comment: Please show your build files (`build.sbt`, `project/plugins.sbt` etc.).

Comment: Thanks for `plugins.sbt`. Please add `build.sbt` too.

Comment: It is pretty big and has proprietary info, what part will be the most helpful?

Comment: The part that reproduces the issue. You can try to delete the proprietary part and check whether the issue remains. If so you can add non-proprietary part.

Comment: Just in case, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yep, looks similar, what is a treatment plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `scala.tools.nsc.Settings` (the method [bootclasspath](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.13/scala-compiler/scala/tools/nsc/Settings.html#bootclasspath:StandardScalaSettings.this.PathSetting)) is from `scala-compiler`

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.12.13

Try to add

```
libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value
```

to your `build.sbt`.

Does this change anything for you?

---

Actually, I managed to reproduce `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.tools.nsc.settings.AbsSettings$AbsSetting scala.tools.nsc.Settings.bootclasspath()` even with fresh Play installation `sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8` (Play 2.7.9, Scala 2.12.13, jdk-17.0.5). Accessing http://localhost:9000/ leads to slightly different stack trace in my case https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/a36fc85966bfcf1481d7ec0b516ffc9f

The stacktrace is even closer to yours with sbt outside IntelliJ: `at play.twirl.compiler...` https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/9f6c3982bb7bd0c715c86f4c4a61a6eb

---

> Play 2.8.0 is the first version were we officially support Java 11. Play, its standalone modules, samples and seeds are all tested against AdoptOpenJDK 8 & 11. We continue to support Java 8 as the default version

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.19/Highlights28#Java-11-support

So Play 2.7 may not work with Java 11.

Try to upgrade to Play 2.8. The issue seems not to reproduce there.

---

One more option (if you'd like to stay on Play 2.7) is to downgrade sbt to 1.3.x (modify `project/build.properties`).

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/6400

https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/pjhex0/error_javalangnosuchmethoderror/

The thing seems to be in a conflict between Play and sbt versions. More precisely, between `twirl-compiler` and `scala-compiler`. `twirl-compiler` doesn't seem to respect patch version 2.12.x of `scala-compiler`. Different patch versions 2.12.x (for different `x`) of `scala-compiler` are generally binary incompatible because it's not API like `scala-library` or `scala-reflect`. But `twirl-compiler` is just `_2.12`, not `_2.12.x`.

```
[IJ][playdemo] $ projects
[info] In file:/playdemo/
[info]   * root
[IJ][playdemo] $ reload plugins
[IJ]projects
[info] In file:/playdemo/project/
[info]   * project
[IJ]dependencyTree
[info] default:project:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
[info]   +-com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.7.9
[info]   | +-...
[info]   | +-com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-twirl:1.4.2
[info]   | | +-com.typesafe.play:twirl-compiler_2.12:1.4.2 [S]
[info]   | |   +-com.typesafe.play:twirl-api_2.12:1.4.2 [S]
[info]   | |   | +-...
[info]   | |   | 
[info]   | |   +-com.typesafe.play:twirl-parser_2.12:1.4.2 [S]
[info]   | |   +-org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.12.15 [S]
[info]   | |     +-...
[info]   | |     +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.12.15 [S]
```

([running sbt command on the meta-build level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882015/running-sbt-command-on-the-meta-build-level))

Maybe this can be debugged like in [SBT gives java.lang.NullPointerException when trying to run spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74440324/sbt-gives-java-lang-nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-run-spark) ...

Comment: No difference, the same outcome

Comment: Works with downgrading sbt to 1.3.12